# Possible ways to test security for Windows Phone 7 or iOS devices

Tags: operating-systems, ios, windows-phone

I'm trying to test the security features of different types of OSs available, and I decided to narrow this down to the Windows Phone 7 and iOS operating systems. I will be testing both my Nokia 800 and iPod Touch 4 to see which one has the better features. The issue I have now is figuring out how to test them. To be blunt, I don't know where to start in this regard. Has anyone here actually tested out embedded systems before?

Comment: Welcome to IT Sec. I am unable to see any security relevant issues in your question. Please give the security relevant issues you are interested in. If there are no security relevant issues then the question belongs on a different site.

Comment: Better features in what respect? Since you decided to test, you should know what features you want to test… What properties do you want to evaluate? What are you going to use the devices for? What are your use cases, your security objectives, your threat model?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to test features then to be honest you don't need the phone so much as documentation about the phone hardware/operating system.

It's worth noting that Windows Phone 7 is not the current version of the OS and if you're looking at a comparison of these two ecosystems then it should really be Windows phone 8  and iOS 6.x .

In terms of comparing Windows Phone 7 and iOS, from  a feature standpoint iOS is going to win a match-up relatively easily as it has a number of security related features (e.g. full-disk encryption, VPN support extensive MDM support) that I don't believe Windows Phone 7 has.

Comment: On the other hand, WP8 would probably win relatively easily for the same reasons, however again it depends on what the OP is looking for, what tradeoffs, etc.